# NullPointer Exception for clob datatype on WLCachedRowSet

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, weblogic12c

I am using weblogic 12.1.1 and oepe to build an java application . I am using WLCachedRowSet class for creating an object for a rowset returned by the sql query . I am using oracle database version 11.1.2.3 .

In my code i am calling `response.getString()` and `response.getClob()` while response.getString works , response.getClob keeps throwing null pointer exception

I am adding the code snippet that is causing the issue

> if(response.getClob("column")!=null)
>                       fr.setResponseText(StringProcessor.clobStringConversion(response.getClob("column"))); // convert clob to string

the only difference i see is string datatype class is `java.lang.String` while clob is `oracle.jdbc.OracleClob`

Has anybody faced this issue before?

Comment: Have you tried Clob cl = response.getClob("column"); String val = clob.getSubString(1, clob.length);, do you get NullPointerException?

Comment: `response.getClob("column")` resolves to a null pointer . so i don think this would help . but i will give it a try

Comment: What is the actual query? What is the actual stack trace for your application's error? :)

Comment: It is a nested exception all i get is java.lang.NPE